# hyperlink the title of a Shiny user interface drop down menu?

Tags: r, shiny

Is it straightforward to add a hyperlink to a drop down header? I'm hoping to have users be able to click on "R Quantile Type" conveniently for more information, and not need to use other precious real estate in addition to the dropdown header itself.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
hist(rnorm(input$r_qtype), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("r_qtype",
    "R Quantile Type",  

  #https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/quantile
              choices = c(4,5,6,7,8,9), selected = 6)  
), 
mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tags$a` we can add a hyperlink

```
selectInput("r_qtype",
tags$a("R Quantile Type",href='https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/quantile'),
...)
```

Edit

```
HTML("<a target='_blank' href='https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/quantile'>R</a> Quantile Type"),
```

Comment: how about if we just wanted part of the dropdown header to be hyperlinked, for example just the "R" tagged in the above example, and leaving "Quantile Type" as regular?

Comment: @doconnor, in that case, you will need low-level HTML which you can pass it using `shiny::HTML` function. See my update

Comment: thank you much @A.Suliman. last question - what if we wanted the link to start a new browser tab?